# How to find out what url HTML button submits to

Tags: html, forms, selenium, python-requests

So I'm scraping a website (instacart.com) and it requires a zip code to determine what data it displays.  I want to use Python requests to post an arbitrary zip code.  The only problem is I don't know what url to post it to and whether it requires any other arguments like an authenticity token or a user cache key.  The zip code is entered via an text box that looks like this:

```
<form data-radium="true">
    <input id="postalcode-16749" 
        name="postal_code" 
        type="text" 
        aria-invalid="false" 
        aria-describedby="" 
        autocomplete="on" 
        placeholder="" 
        data-radium="true" 
        value="" style=(super long block of css stuff)>
</form>
```

and then posted via a button that looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" 
    data-radium="true" 
    style="touch-action: manipulation; (long block of more css)">
    Continue
</button>
```

I don't know a lot about web programming, but I was taught in school that HTML forms would look more like this: `<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">` and you could use the `action` attribute to find where it was posting to.  Is there a way to use the developer console to find what I'm looking for?  How can I post a zip code to this website with Python?

Edit: I did a little more digging and I found that the request payload is {"current_zip_code":"some_zip_code"}, and that it's actually not using POST, it's using PUT.  There's still a problem though, the request url looks like this: `https://www.instacart.com/v3/bundle?source=web&cache_key=` and then there's a different code each time for the cache_key.  How do I know what url to post to?

Comment: This question is not really related to Python.

Comment: It kind of is, because I'd like someone to explain how I can use requests to post the zip code, not just how to find the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer in case anyone tries to do a similar thing.  I found the url the button posts to and its parameters by looking in the network tab of the developer console and clicking the button.  Then I ran into the problem that the url it sends the PUT request to changes every time, always ending in a different `cache_key`.

The solution was to use a python module called `seleniumwire` to simulate a browser and then grab all the network traffic.  From there I looped through it and found urls containing `cache_key=` and stored everything after that as a string.  Then tacked that string to the end of this url: `https://www.instacart.com/v3/bundle?source=web&cache_key=` and went back to using requests.

hope this helps someone!